# Change Url value on runtime when debugging code

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

I'm trying to change the value on ***runtime*** when debugging the code.

Here is the screenshot.
[image]

Need to change the **url** when renaming `{http://jack.hotels.services.inataravel.local/api/hotels/}` to `{http://xyz.hotels.services.inataravel.local/api/hotels/}` it shows error [image]

So how do I change ths `BaseAddress` value URL on the debugging mode. Even if I remove `{}` from the URL it gives the error as.
[image]

Comment: you try to change the object... expand that object and change the string value

Comment: @Den won't change in the object as the edit value shows gray.

Comment: Could you share us the way you edited/changed the `BaseAddress`? Also, is it possible to let us know the whole codes where you assigned the URL value? BTW, check whether these/related symbols are missing: `""` `()` `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use VisualStudio Immediate Window and assign new Uri() value to the httpClient.BaseAddress. Really not sure that it won't break underline logic of HttpClient but it does what you asked for[image]